# System time drifts terribly on Ubuntu 12.04.5 Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, time, clock

I have a problem of system time drift on my newly-installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 dual boot with Windows 8.1. By the word terribly, the drift is clearly noticeable by your eyes when looking at the seconds of the time. By running the logging to check the drift in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138916/why-is-ubuntus-clock-getting-slower-or-faster), the drift is 1800 seconds per hour. You can see the drift in this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuiuf67lhpqy9s5/VID_20150513_164222_392.mp4?dl=0). The hardware clock seems to be synced to the system time too.

However, when I go to the clock in BIOS and Windows 8.1 and time it with my watch for a few minutes, there is no problem at all.

Just if these information affect the problem:

- When I installed my Ubuntu, I have to turn acpi=off so that I can boot into my LiveUSB (My PC's mainboard is Asus p9x79 Deluxe and I cannot boot Ubuntu with acpi on).
- Sometimes the keyboard gives repeating output when typing. I think this is also the result of speeding time.
- Seems like the computer is on overclock. I don't know much about what have been done to this computer before I got it from my lab.

If any further information is needed, please ask.

Comment: To debug this, stop the currently running NTP daemon: `sudo service ntp stop`, then restart with no sanity checks and debugging on: `sudo ntpd -qdg`, and post the output here. Then, restart ntp: `sudo service ntp start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after dmesg | grep unstable I got
`Marking TSC unstable due to check_tsc_sync_source failed`

Putting this message into Google I found http://www.overclock.net/t/1347771/sb-e-marking-tsc-unstable-due-to-check-tsc-sync-source-failed-xpost-intel-cpus that has same problem with similar mainboard Asus P9X79 (mine is Deluxe, theirs is Pro.) They suggest the problem is with the BIOS and in a comment on page 4, they said that BIOS version 4701 can solve this. So, I tried updating BIOS to 4701 and everything works fine until now.

Seems like this mainboard is having compatibility problem with Ubuntu.

Sorry for asking and solving it too fast.